# Need to get value of a text field, using a concatenated string for the id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

Hi I'm not very good at explaining this in the right terms but I'm trying to retrieve the value of a textbox. The textboxes are in a table and each row has one and the id of each is made up of a unique id and a name... 
html

```
<label id="labelref<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>" name="labelref<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>"></label>
<input type="text" id="save<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>" name="saveref<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>" style="margin-right:5px;" />
<a href="javascript:saveref('<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>');" id="aref<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>" style="margin-right:5px;">Save</a>
<label id="errorref<?php echo $row_list['pp_order_details_id']; ?>" style="color:red; margin-right:5px;"></label>
```

javascript/jquery

```
function save(order_id) {
    var newSaveRef = "saveref"+order_id;    
    var saveref = $('#newSaveRef').val();
    alert(saveref); 
}
```

I want the value of save ref. If this value ($row_list['pp_order_details_id'];) is SS16363 then this value (newSaveRef) should be saverefSS16363.

but how do I get the value from the textbox with that ID????

Comment: I think you already have the desired id in newSaveRed but you are using a string as Id in jQuery selector. Try var saveref = $("#"+ newSaveRef).val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
var saveref  =  $('#saveref' + order_id + '' ).val();
```

Answer (score 3):

`newSaveRef` is a variable, so concatenate it with a hash `#` to use the variable to find an element with that id.

```
var saveref = $('#' + newSaveRef).val();
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for! I couldn't get it right.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function save(order_id) {
    var newSaveRef = "#saveref"+order_id;    
    var saveref = $(newSaveRef).val();
    alert(saveref); 
}
```

You were using a string literal rather than the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
function save(order_id) {
    var newSaveRef = "saveref"+order_id;    
    var saveref = $('#'+newSaveRef).val();
    alert(saveref); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#newSaveRef").val();
```

Has to be:

```
$('#' + newSaveRef).val();
```